# How should you define regular functions in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mvw

I have some experience in AngularJS, but the fact that I can't figure out how to handle a regular function inside a AngularJS controller keeps bothering me. For the record I am talking about a function that handles parts of small business logic inside the controller, that doesn't need to be shared across controllers. I have found two ways to handle such regular functions that don't need binding from the view.

The first way I have found is to just use: `$scope.myFunction = function(){}` but the fact that it can be used directly from the view doesn't seem correct.

The second way I have found is to just use a regular Javascript function: `function myFunction(){}` but I don't know how the visibility of such functions is in AngularJS.

Is there a "correct" way of ensuring a limited visibility inside a controller? Or should I keep using the regular Javascript function?

Comment: you should use service/factory

Comment: If you define it in $scope then it will be only visible within the controller of that scope, so why not do it that way?

Comment: @JeetendraChauhan because it is about a function that can only be used inside that controller, and has no use wathsoever in another controller.

Comment: @Ahmad but than it can be accessed from the view, couldn't that be a problem in some cases?

Comment: @StefCoenen it would be, I dont see why would that be a problem now or later

Comment: @Ahmed that is not correct. It will be visible to any child controllers if it is declared on `$scope`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just the same way as you would define a "local" function within a standard closure:

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    var localFunc = function() {
        // Internal function, only available to code executed after
        // localFunc is declared
    };
    function localFuncHoisted() {
        // Internal function, doesn't matter where it is declared
        // will be visible to all internal methods
    }
    $scope.globalFunc = function() {
        // Available from the controller
    }
}]);
```

`localFunc` and `localFuncHoisted` are identical in most cases, however each has its own benefits. The hosted function is visible to all code, before and after declaration. `localFunc` can be set only when needed and removed when not.

Comment: So the localFunc would be preferred in my use case, correct?

Comment: @StefCoenen I've added clarification for `localFunc` and `localFuncHoisted`. The two are mostly equivalent, but you might decide to use one depending on your exact case.

Comment: Just to be sure, the only difference is that the `localFunc` is only accessible after declaration and the `LocalFuncHost` is accessible in the complete controller and only in the controller, not in other controllers?

Comment: @StefCoenen Exactly. Neither is visible outside of the Controller